# Adding a Cookie policy Popup message

Tags: magento-1, modal-popup

I was wondering would anybody be able to assist me.

I want to add a pop up on my magento 1 website that tells the user about our cookie policy.

I know there is a setting in magento already but it doesn’t look great on our website.

Has anyone implemented their own pop up message ?

And willing to give me some help or sample code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, its simple way to create and it will work.

```
<script>
function createDivCookie(){

 cookieName = 'testCookie';
 cookieDuration = 14; //days  
 createCookie(window.cookieName,window.cookieValue, window.cookieDuration); // Create the cookie
 //Place Your Code to Show Popup message

 }

 if(checkCookie(window.cookieName) != window.cookieValue){
    createDivCookie(); //it will check cookies created or not
 }
</script>
```